# How to make vertices child to empties/objects

Tags: vertices, parent

I want to build a plane whose four vertices follow the path of four empties. The plane has an image, and I used the "Image-as-planes" add-on to setup the plane.

To parent each of the vertices to each empty, I use the following procedure:

- select the plane
- tab into object mode
- select the vertice
- tab to leave object mode
- shift-click to add the empty as parent
- ctrl-P

however, I can't link more than one vertix to an empty. As soon as I parent another empty, the previous one is unlinked.

I am aware this is probably something very basic, but I couldn't find how to do that in any other way.

Comment: Hello :). I believe in this case the [Hook Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/hooks.html#hook-modifier) might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks, but an empty does not have object modifiers. I'll see if I can use a regular object and the hook modifier.

Answer (score 5):

Found it:

- select the empty
- shift-select the object that contains the vertices
- tab to edit mode
- select the vertex that you want to link the the empty
- on the vertex menu, hook to object
- repeat for the other vertices